# sudo apt-get update vs upgrade vs install

Tags: server, updates

Ok, I need to know what is the proper way for me to update all the software packages?

From what I gather I need to run the **sudo apt-get update** first, but
then do I run the **upgrade** or the **install** command?

...and last but not least, do I restart the server?

Answer (score 2):

Read `man apt-get`, `man apt`, and `man apt-cache`.

The command to find a software package (I know you didn't ask this, but it's important) is:

```
apt-cache search <keyword>
```

whil will return a list of packages and their descriptions.

Then, you can use:

```
sudo apt-get install <packages>
```

to install desired packages.

To find and apply needed updates (you called it "update all the software packages"), First update the package version database with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Only after this finishes will the packaging system know which installed packages have more recent versions available.

Then, to apply the package upgrades:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Once the upgrade finishes look for files called `/var/run/reboot*`. If these file exist, they'll contain hints about why your system needs to be rebooted. For example, I remember seeing the package name `linux-base` in `/var/run/reboot*`, when I'd upgraded `linux-base` and needed to reboot. If there is NO `/var/run/reboot*` file, no reboot is needed.